# Change the language in community URL with Language parameter(Guest user license)

Tags: community-builder, site.com, language

I am having requirement where in I am opening a Community URL [Link](https://sandbox-ability-java-4450-dev-ed-17b98201c8f.cs94.force.com/ClinicalPatientEngagement/s/accept-privacy-policy?language=en_US&data=BnXN9CUG2yY10rGgnnXfUQ9l%2FovTeITIlvJJ%20nk5AIxb6g2rdq9NfLTM6Rd%2FkzXo) from welcome Email which has language parameter appended in the URL. I need to change this language parameter before receiving the mail. I have tried changing:

- Logged in community user Language & locale.
- Changed the community default language from Builder.
- Changed the browser default language.

But this language parameter does not change and always has **language=en_US**. I even checked my code to see if this parameter is getting passed from there but this seems to something Out of box functionality for Sites.
I need to know from where this language parameter is getting passed, so that I can fetch that language and use in query.